# Showing that a series converges uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am trying to show that $\sum (-1)^n \frac{e^{-nx}}{k}$ converges uniformly on $[0,\infty)$. My reasoning is as follows: $|\sum_{k = m}^{n} (-1)^k \frac{e^{-kx}}{k}| \leq \frac{e^{-mx}}{m} \leq \frac{1}{m}$.

Thus given $\epsilon>0$, select N such that $1/N <\epsilon$ and then for $n\geq m\geq N$ we have $|\sum_{k = m}^{n} (-1)^k \frac{e^{-kx}}{k}|<\epsilon$ and so the partial sums form a Cauchy sequence and the estimate on the right hand side above is independent of $x$ which means that the partial sums converge uniformly $\Rightarrow$ the series converges uniformly.

Is this correct?

Comment: Is the variable of summation $k $ or $n $? Both variables appear in your sum.

Comment: oh whoops, the original summation is over n, the estimate is over k, ill edit it.

Comment: Changed another k to an m...my bad

Comment: Your reasoning is nice, except that you do not provide any reason for your very first estimate (Dirichlets criterion?!)